# Problem with download file via CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem when i try download file with curl php.

Headers response

[image]

PHP Code

```
$filePath = $this->exchangePath . $this->exchangeFile;
$url = $this->exchangeURL;

$fp = fopen($filePath, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Preview file data after downloading (106Kb)

[image]

Preview file data on server (1.9 Mb - The file will be bigger in the future. Maybe 300Mb or large.)

[image]

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you're ignoring that `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. The server returns the data gzip-encoded, and you're not un-gzipping it.

Luckily for you, curl has built-in support for gzip decoding (curl has basically supported gzip and deflate decoding forever, but modern versions of curl also support br and zstd)

to enable automatic decoding of supported encodings, simply set

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');
```

- setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to emptystring turns on automatic decoding of all supported encodings.

aalso, you should use the fopen binary mode `wb` so Windows doesn't fuck with your `\n` bytes.

Comment: Thank you so match. This option helpd me.
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');

Comment: @KarionovViktor btw if you need to parse very large 100+MB XML files, you should check out https://github.com/alex-oleshkevich/php-fast-xml-parser  - i recently ported a DOMDocument-based parser, that was using ~80 minutes to parse a 120MB XML file, to php-fast-xml-parser, and it parsed the same file in 10 seconds, compared to DOMDocument's 80 minutes :O